# Screen resolution hides right part of screen

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, resolution

I was trying to get my second monitor working on XP and I ran into a problem my screen resolution even if it is the normal one hides part of my screen, here is an image:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Difficult to understand your question. Are you using Windows XP? Are you using a laptop? Are you trying to extend your screen using an external monitor? Give more details

Comment: In addition, does your monitor have an "auto-adjust" setting? Try this and see if the screen re-fits properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some monitors have an "auto-adjust" button/menu feature that re-adjusts the picture onto the display and often fixes symptoms of part of the screen being "cut off".